# Automatically hide toolbar when it is not in use

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, toolbar

I am creating a Cocoa Application for Mac OS 10.6 >, and I want to hide the toolbar of an NSWindow automatically when it is not in use for at least 30 seconds.
I think this can be done with NSTimers, but I'm not familiar with them and I don't know how I can implement this.

Another problem is that both the NSToolbarDelegate and NSWindowDelegate protocols don't have delegate methods like `toolbarDidShow:`

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

---

PS. This is not to punish the user, but rather give the user a cleaner window (the window consist of only a toolbar for color and font and a text-view).

---

PPS. Can the hide-toolbar-animation lead into a problem with the cursor while the user is typing?

Answer (score 0):

> I think this can be done with NSTimers, but I'm not familiar with them and I don't know how I can implement this.

The [Timer Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000061i) might help you here.  It's easy enough to show and hide the toolbar, use [-setVisible:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000681-BAJCIEFJ).  Also, -isVisible can be used to determine the visibility of the toolbar.